# In Node.js crypto how to use RSA keys but not as a PEM format?

Tags: node.js, npm, encryption, rsa, cryptojs

I am using crypto's generateKeyPair function() to generate a pair of RSA public and private keys

```
generateKeyPair(
                "rsa",
                {
                    modulusLength: 4096,
                    publicKeyEncoding: {
                        type: "spki",
                        format: "pem"
                    },
                    privateKeyEncoding: {
                        type: "pkcs8",
                        format: "pem",
                        cipher: "aes-256-cbc",
                        passphrase: "top secret"
                    }
                },
                (err, publicKey, privateKey) => {
                   //do something here
                }
```

I am getting the keys in PEM format. But I want them in string format so that I can share it with the client side and also persist it to db(MongoDB). Is this a good way to do things? If so how can I get strings from PEM and encrypt/decrypt successfully? If its not a good way what would be a better approach?

I am using the following function to extract the string from the PEM:

```
getBase64PubKey = function(pem) {
        var b64Lines = pem.replace("\n", "");
        var b64Prefix = b64Lines.replace("-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----", "");
        var b64Final = b64Prefix.replace("-----END PUBLIC KEY-----", "");
        return b64Final;
    };
```

and something like the following to build it back (where `keynew` is the key in string format) before encrypting:

```
var pem =
        "-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----\n" + keynew + "-----END PUBLIC KEY-----\n";
```

I am getting error **Error: Failed to read asymmetric key**.